# C++ CreateThread() "Not responding"

Tags: c++, multithreading, loops

I am creating a thread which can control all program procedure messages and not freeze the program. I have written [this code](http://aliarth.lt/CreateThread.txt) and I got `program not responding`.

Does anyone have experience with threads and can help me?

Comment: The basic guidelines here on Stack Overflow require questions seeking debugging help to include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the _shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 1):

Win32 message loops are per thread - in other words, your thread will never receive the event for `VK_ESCAPE` occuring on the main thread.